# Invoke webservice using HTTPS in Java

Tags: java, web-services, security, jax-ws, webservices-client

My webserice provider provides HTTPS services and I need to consume them. I'm using JAX-WS and invoking the webservice with given HTTPS URL, The response is coming as expected, but when I see the logs it says HTTP request and the request XML is not encrypted, I enabled

```
"com.sun.xml.internal.ws.transport.http.client.HttpTransportPipe.dump=true;"
```

to print the logs in console.

Is that a behavior when we print XML in console,
If I want to see encrypted XML, What should I do

I'm not sure whether encryption is happening when transmitting the request.

Answer (score 1):

If you are on Linux, you can use Socket Stat `ss -pr` for inspecting open sockets (and whether they are secure). On BSD (but also on Linux), use `netstat`, while I'm sure there is a similar tool also on Windows, although I never used one.

Otherwise, use a network inspecting tool like [Wireshark](http://www.wireshark.org/) or Tcpflow/Tcpdump and see whether the messages are sent over HTTPS or not.

Note: these tools will only confirm that a TLS/SSL connection is present, they cannot substitute a thorough security audit.